# Can we use rest api in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, rest, api

I am new in Rest Api and I am using this api in SharePoint but I just wanna know that can I use Rest Api in Asp.Net with web forms.

Please let me know if we can do this or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it it's simple you can get help and learn about your first WEB API from here.

[REST Web API][1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

you can access it via third party tool also like PostMan and etc.

Answer (score 0):

OFC that you can. There is a framework called ASP.NET Web API.  https://www.asp.net/web-api